# how to show all text (Flutter)?

Tags: flutter

how to show the text in full? I'm getting this error (on the screen).

what should I change in my code? Is there any way to do it? In case you want to see the code please let me know I will update more.

read_mode.dart

```
import 'package:carousel_slider/carousel_slider.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:quiz2/const/state.dart';
import 'package:flutter_riverpod/flutter_riverpod.dart';
import 'package:quiz2/database/category_provider.dart';
import 'package:quiz2/database/db_helper.dart';
import 'package:quiz2/database/question_provider.dart';
import 'package:quiz2/model/user_answer_model.dart';
import 'package:quiz2/utils/utils.dart';
import 'package:quiz2/widgets/question_body.dart';
import 'package:shared_preferences/shared_preferences.dart';

class ReadModePage extends StatefulWidget {
  ReadModePage({Key key, this.title}):super(key: key);
 final String title; 

  @override
  _ReadModePageState createState() => _ReadModePageState();
}

class _ReadModePageState extends State<ReadModePage> {

  SharedPreferences prefs;
  int indexPage = 0;
  CarouselController buttonCarouselController = CarouselController();
  List<UserAnswer> userAnswers = new List<UserAnswer>();
 
  @override
  void initState() { 
    super.initState();
    WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) async{
       prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
       indexPage = await prefs.getInt("${context.read(questionCategoryState).state.name}_${context.read(questionCategoryState).state.ID}") ?? 0;
    
    print('Save index page: ${indexPage}');
    Future.delayed(Duration(milliseconds: 500)).then((value) => buttonCarouselController.animateToPage(indexPage));
    
    });
  }
 
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var questionModule = context.read(questionCategoryState).state;
    return WillPopScope(child: Scaffold(
       appBar: AppBar(title: Text(questionModule.name),
       leading: GestureDetector(onTap: () => showCloseDialog(questionModule),
       child: Icon(Icons.arrow_back), ),),
       body: Container(
         color: Colors.teal[100],
         child: FutureBuilder<List<Question>>(
           future: getQuestionByCategory(questionModule.ID),
           builder: (context, snapshot){
              if(snapshot.hasError)
                  return Center(
                    child: Text('${snapshot.error}'),);
                 else if(snapshot.hasData)
                 {
                  if(snapshot.data.length>0) 
                  {
                    return Container(margin: const EdgeInsets.all(5.0),
                    alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
                    child: Card(
                     elevation: 20,
                     child: Container(
                       child: SingleChildScrollView(
                         child: Column(children: [
                           SizedBox(height: 15,),
                           QuestionBody(context: context,
                           carouselController: buttonCarouselController,
                           questions: snapshot.data,
                           userAnswers: userAnswers,),
                           SizedBox(height: 30,),
                           Row(
                             mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                             children: [
                               TextButton(onPressed: () => showAnswer(context), child: Text("Show Answer")) 
                             ],)
                         ],)
                        )
                    )                    
                  ));
                  
                  }
                  else return Center(
                    child: Text('Category don\'n have any question'));
                 } else
                    return Center(
                    child: CircularProgressIndicator(),);
           }
         ),
        ),
       ), onWillPop: () async{
         showCloseDialog(questionModule);
          return true;
    });
  }

showCloseDialog(Category questionModule) {
   showDialog(
     context: context, 
     builder:(_) => new AlertDialog(
       title: Text('Close'),
       content: Text("Do you want to save this question index?"),
       actions: [
         TextButton(onPressed: (){
           Navigator.of(context).pop(); //close dialog
           Navigator.pop(context); //close screen
         }, child: Text("No")),
         TextButton(onPressed: (){
           prefs.setInt("${context.read(questionCategoryState).state.name}_${context.read(questionCategoryState).state.ID}",
            context.read(currentReadPage).state);

           Navigator.of(context).pop(); //close dialog
           Navigator.pop(context); //close screen
         }, child: Text("Yes"))
       ],)    
     );
  }
}

Future <List<Question>> getQuestionByCategory(int id) async{

  var db = await copyDB();
  var result = await QuestionProvider().getQuestionCategoryId(db, id);
  return result;

}
```

question_body.dart

```
import 'package:auto_size_text/auto_size_text.dart';
import 'package:carousel_slider/carousel_controller.dart';
import 'package:carousel_slider/carousel_slider.dart';
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter_riverpod/flutter_riverpod.dart';
import 'package:quiz2/const/state.dart';
import 'package:quiz2/database/question_provider.dart';
import 'package:quiz2/model/user_answer_model.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:quiz2/utils/utils.dart';

class QuestionBody extends StatelessWidget {
  QuestionBody({Key key,
  this.context,
  this.userAnswers,
  this.carouselController,
  this.questions}):super(key:key);
  
   

   BuildContext context;
   List<UserAnswer> userAnswers;
   CarouselController carouselController;
   List<Question> questions;
  
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context){
    return CarouselSlider(
      carouselController: carouselController,
      items: questions.asMap().entries.map((e) => Builder(
      builder: (context) {
        return Consumer(builder: (context, watch, _){
           
           var userAnswerState = watch(userAnswerSelected).state;
           var isShowAnswer = watch(isEnableShowAnswer).state;

           return Column(
             children: [
               Expanded(
                 child: Column(
                   children: [
                     Text( //Question
                       context.read(isTestMode).state ? "${e.key+1}: ${e.value.questionText}": 
               "${e.value.questionId}: ${e.value.questionText}",
               style: TextStyle(height:2, fontSize: 16)), 
                     Visibility(//Question is image
                       visible: (e.value.isImageQuestion == null || e.value.isImageQuestion == 0 ? false:true),
                       child: Container(
                       height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height/15*2,
                       child: e.value.isImageQuestion == 0 ? Container():
                       Image.network("${e.value.questionImage}",
                       fit: BoxFit.fill,)
                     )), 
                     Expanded( //Answer A
                       child: ListTile(
                         title: AutoSizeText('${e.value.answerA}',
                         style: TextStyle(color: isShowAnswer ? e.value.correctAnswer == 'A' ? Colors.red : Colors.grey:Colors.black),
                         ),
                         leading: Radio(
                           value: "A",
                           groupValue: getGroupValue(isShowAnswer,e,userAnswerState),
                           onChanged: (value) => setUserAnswer(context,e,value),
                           ),
                       )),
                       Expanded( //Answer B
                       child: ListTile(
                         title: AutoSizeText('${e.value.answerB}',
                         style: TextStyle(color: isShowAnswer ? e.value.correctAnswer == 'B' ? Colors.red : Colors.grey:Colors.black),
                         ),
                         leading: Radio(
                           value: "B",
                           groupValue: getGroupValue(isShowAnswer,e,userAnswerState),
                           onChanged: (value) => setUserAnswer(context,e,value),
                           ),
                       )),
                       Expanded( //Answer C
                       child: ListTile(
                         title: AutoSizeText('${e.value.answerC}',
                         style: TextStyle(color: isShowAnswer ? e.value.correctAnswer == 'C' ? Colors.red : Colors.grey:Colors.black),
                         ),
                         leading: Radio(
                           value: "C",
                           groupValue: getGroupValue(isShowAnswer,e,userAnswerState),
                           onChanged: (value) => setUserAnswer(context,e,value),
                           ),
                       )),
                       Expanded( //Answer D
                       child: ListTile(
                         title: AutoSizeText('${e.value.answerD}',
                         style: TextStyle(color: isShowAnswer ? e.value.correctAnswer == 'D' ? Colors.red : Colors.grey:Colors.black),
                         ),
                         leading: Radio(
                           value: "D",
                           groupValue: getGroupValue(isShowAnswer,e,userAnswerState),
                           onChanged: (value) => setUserAnswer(context,e,value),
                           ),
                       ))

               ],
               )),
             ],
           );
        },
      );
      },
      )).toList(), options: CarouselOptions(
        autoPlay: false,
        enlargeCenterPage: true,
        viewportFraction: 0.9,
        initialPage: 0,
        height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height/5*2,
        onPageChanged: (page,_){
          context.read(currentReadPage).state = page;
          context.read(isEnableShowAnswer).state = false;
        }
      ));
  }
  
 getGroupValue(bool isShowAnnswer, MapEntry<int, Question> e, UserAnswer userAnswerState){
   return isShowAnnswer ? e.value.correctAnswer : (context.read(isTestMode).state ?
   context.read(userListAnswer).state[e.key].answered:'');
 }

}
```

Is there any way to do it? In case you want to see the code please let me know I will update more.

screen
[image]

Comment: Hi There. Your widget tree structure seems a bit misshapen. Could you elaborate what you are actually trying to achieve ? Do you want your `show answer` button to be always visible at the bottom of the `Card` and the other content to scroll ? If yes, I have a better structure suggestion that will solve it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your widget tree seems a bit complicated for no reason.

Assuming what you wanted to achieve was to have your `Show Answer` button always be visible at the bottom of the `Card` and the other content on the top of this button to scroll itself inside the `Card`, this is a much better way to have the structure,

```
class Minimal extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: Text('Minimal')),
      body: Container(
        margin: const EdgeInsets.all(5.0),
        alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
        child: Card(
          elevation: 20,
          child: Container(
            height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height / 5 * 2,
            child: Column(
              children: [
                Expanded(
                  child: SingleChildScrollView(
                    child: Column(
                      children: [
                        SizedBox(height: 15),
                        Container(
                          color: Colors.deepOrange,
                          width: double.infinity,
                          child: Column(
                            children: [
                              // Replace this Text with your QuestionBody
                              Text('asdasd \nasdasd \nasdasd \nasdasd \nasdasd \nasdasd \nasdasd \nasdasd \nasdasd \nasdasd \nasdasd \nasdasd \nasdasd \nasdasd \nasdasd \nasdasd \nasdasd \nasdasd \nasdasd \nasdasd \n'),
                            ],
                          ),
                        ),
                        SizedBox(height: 30),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                Row(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                  children: [TextButton(onPressed: () {}, child: Text("Show Answer"))],
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Now, your `QuestionBody` also seems to have some unnecessary stuff.

Instead of having,

```
return Column(
  children: [
    Expanded(
      child: Column(
        children: [
          Text( //Question
```

Just do,

```
return Column(
  children: [
    Text( //Question
```

Finally remove the `height` restriction from the `CarouselOptions` since we already gave that `height` to the `Container` inside the `Card`.

Comment: thank you, but I have new questions :D Where we can speak with you? If you don't mind.

Comment: Hi. You can join this chat room and ask your questions. I will get back to you once I am available. https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/233260/discussion

Answer (score 0):

Either give your parent widget more height or wrap your text inside a `SingleChildScrollView` for example to make the text scrollable

Comment: Neither of these solutions help OP. She already has a `SingleChildScrollView` and the use case is to have fixed height. So this is kinda misleading.